# Does H2's MySQL compatibility mode support MySQL's "SET" type?

Tags: mysql, h2, compatibility, in-memory-database

I see that it supports ENUM, but I haven't been able to find anything on the SET type (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html).

If H2 does not support it, is there another in-memory database engine that has more complete MySQL support? Thanks!